# Is there a way to achieve this subplot look writing less?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to learn some python and I've tried to plot some data. I was able to do it, sure, but to achieve the look I wanted I add to write way too much code. And I guess there is a way to do it in a much simpler way.

[image: plots]

What I'm trying to is

1. Set the same x-axis limit for all subplots
2. Remove the plot box and leave only the x-axis

To achieve this I had to write all this

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))
axes[0, 0].plot(data1['Hz'], data1['int_n'])
axes[0, 1].plot(data2['Hz'], data2['int_n'])
axes[1, 0].plot(data3['Hz'], data3['int_n'])
axes[1, 1].plot(data4['Hz'], data4['int_n'])
axes[0, 0].set_xlim(100, 20)
axes[0, 1].set_xlim(100, 20)
axes[1, 0].set_xlim(100, 20)
axes[1, 1].set_xlim(100, 20)
axes[0, 0].set_title('Sample 1')
axes[0, 1].set_title('Sample 2')
axes[1, 0].set_xlabel('Hz')
axes[1, 1].set_xlabel('Hz')
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('Experiment 1')
axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('Experiment 2')
axes[0, 0].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axes[0, 1].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axes[1, 0].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axes[1, 1].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axes[0, 0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes[0, 0].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes[0, 0].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axes[0, 1].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes[0, 1].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes[0, 1].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 0].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 0].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 1].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 1].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes[1, 1].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
fig.tight_layout()
```

I guess there is an easy way to do it with less text, but I'm not aware of how to do it

Comment: You can make it a bit shorter using loops, but not much shorter, your code is pretty fine.

Comment: Not quite comfortable with loops yet, but I will look into it. Thanks for adding the image I was not able to do it due to low rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop over a flattened instance of `axes`. To make things a little easier, you can also use `zip` and iterate over your `data` instances at the same time. For example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))

for ax, data in zip(axes.flat, (data1, data2, data3, data4)):

    # Do these to all axes instances
    ax.plot(data['Hz'], data['int_n'])    
    ax.set_xlim(100, 20)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

    # loop over the spines we want to turn off
    for spine in ['right', 'top', 'left']:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

# These things only apply to one or two axes, so are outside the loop
axes[0, 0].set_title('Sample 1')
axes[0, 1].set_title('Sample 2')
axes[1, 0].set_xlabel('Hz')
axes[1, 1].set_xlabel('Hz')
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('Experiment 1')
axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('Experiment 2')

fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: That looks a bit more simple. Thanks

Comment: `[ax.spines[p].set_visible(False) for p in ['right', 'top', 'left']]` This would make it even shorter.

Comment: @r-beginners, Indeed, but at some point you start to cross from more succinct to less readable.